# Use macro to email document, and CC another user

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a spreadsheet with a macro button that forwards the document to a specific user in an email. I have been asked to now have the email send to the original recipient and CC another email address.

I tried editing the code as seen below, the email is sent to both however I don't know how to move the second email address to the CC line.

Can you please help?

Application.Dialogs(xlDialogSendMail).Show arg1:=Array("user1@companyx.com", "CCuser@companyx.com"), _
                      arg2:="Your Fun Email"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

xlDialogueSendMail doesn't support CC addresses. You'll probably need to switch over to the Outlook library or whatever library supports your email client.

VBA for a quick and dirty outlook email:

```
Sub sendOutlookEmail()
    Dim outlook As Object
    Dim outlookMail As Object

    Set outlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set outlookMail = outlook.CreateItem(0)

    With outlookMail
        .To = "Your.To@email.com"
        .CC = "Your.CC@email.com"
        .BCC = "Your.BCC@email.com"
        .Subject = "A Subject"
        .Body = "A body"
        .Attachments.Add ThisWorkbook.FullName
        .Display
    End With


End Sub
```

Comment: Do you mind pointing me to the direction to do that, yes I am using Outlook.

Comment: I've added some quick VBA for sending an email via Outlook. The Outlook library is pretty robust, so as new requests come down the pipeline you should be able to adapt the code to do whatever is needed.

Comment: I don't want to sound completely useless (but I am, so I will). Which parts of that code need to be changed to work? does the code read ".Add ThisWorkbook.FullName" or do I need to change that to the workbook's name?

Comment: If you are wanting to mail the current workbook, then the code will work and you'll only need to change the .To, .CC, .BCC, .Subject, and .Body to suit your needs. You can also delete any of those lines that you don't want. The one caveat is that the workbook you are using has to be saved first. You can't just pop open a new workbook, paste this in and run it. Once it's saved, the `ThisWorkbook.FullName` will return the file path of the workbook and Outlook will happily attach it.

Comment: back again.... how can I replace .Subject = "A Subject" with a cell reference? Well specifically 2 cells concatenated?

Comment: That should probably be a new question... but: .Subject = Sheets("YourSheetName").Range("A5").value would grab the the value from cell A5 in sheet "YourSheetName"

Comment: Thank you ever so much! So I don't have to hunt you down in future is there an idiots guide to this stuff you recommend?

Comment: I'm sure there are some VBA for newbies out there, but you can always just google the problem you are looking to solve and hack it from there.

Comment: Note: `.Attachments.Add ThisWorkbook.FullName` line would fail if the workbook has not been saved at least once and it is still with a default Name of BooK1 etc. `ThisWorkbook.Save` can be used to before populating OutlookMail object with its attributes.